# save function only for particular arguments to file

Tags: variable-definitions, save

Define

`f[2] = 3`
`f[3] = 5`

I know how to save the function to file: `Put[Definition[f],"filename.m"]` (or use Save[]).

Now I want to save-to-file the definition and value of f[2], but not of f[3], i.e. something like

`Put[Definition[f[2]],"filename.m"]`

so that the contents of filename.m would be "f[2] = 3", and no entry for f[3] -- and so when I read in that filename.m in another session, only f[2] is defined, no f[3].

How do I do that? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! How general do you want the solution to be? Is it really only about ``f[2]`` and ``f[3]``, or is there actually something more complicated? Otherwise, my convoluted attempt: ``First@Cases[DownValues[f], HoldPattern[_[f[2]] :> val_] :> ToString[HoldForm[f[2] = val]]]`` then you can export it with ``Export["filename.m", %]``

Comment: Ah, and then ToExpression[Import["filename.m"]] to import somewhere else? Clever: You convert the expression into a string, and export that.
You are of course right: What I need is much more complicated. I try to export a function of several arguments which is actually a different InterpolatingFunction[] for each argument, say
```f[2,m,w,q]=Interpolation[{2,3,7,9}]```
```f[3,z,w,q]=Interpolation[{3,4,8,9.10}]```
just to give a small working example...

Comment: ...and I just realised why you asked: Indeed, for a complicated function like an interpolation over, say 100 points in 2 dimensions, this solution truncates the INterpolation[] by using "<><><>" etc, and the output is gibberish... ToExpression[Import[]] returns therefore "ToExpression::sntx: 
   Invalid syntax in or before ..."

Comment: Use Domen's idea:
```outArg[fu_,args_,fle_]:=Module[{nam,lst,stg},
nam=ToExpression[ToString[StringForm["DownValues[``]",fu]]];lst=Table[ToString[nam[[i,1]]],{i,1,Length[nam]}];Do[lst=Select[lst,(StringContainsQ[#,", "<>ToString[arg]<>","]\[Or]StringContainsQ[#,","<>ToString[arg]<>"]"]\[Or]StringContainsQ[#,"["<>ToString[arg]<>","]\[Or]StringContainsQ[#,"["<>ToString[arg]<>"]"])&],{arg,args}];CreateFile[fle];Do[stg=StringDrop[StringDelete[lst[[i]],"HoldPattern["],-1]<>" = ";WriteLine[fle,stg];Put[ReleaseHold[ToExpression[StringDelete[lst[[i]],"_"]]],fle],{i,1,Length[lst]}];Close[fle]]```